# React Native fetch TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am creating my 1st rect native app. Running on OSX using OS11 Iphone 6 simulator. Getting below error in https fetch call. Using XCode 9.

```
ExceptionsManager.js:73 TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.js:441)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:548)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:487
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:306)
    at MessageQueue.js:108
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:269)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:107)
```

React component fetch code. (which is sample code from react-native official example)

```
   getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
        return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                return responseJson.movies;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

Do i really need to update info.pllist to enable Allow Arbitrary Loads ? I tried enabling that too once but did not work.

Package.json 

`{
  "name": "rnstarter",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "^0.49.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}`

Comment: After disconnecting from my employer's network it started working. Strange that i can hit facebook api using my browser even when i am connected to employer's network.

Answer (score 0):

After disconnecting from my employer's network it started working. Strange that i can hit facebook api using my browser even when i am connected to employer's network.

Comment: because of your employer is using an VPN probably :)