# Axios Network Error in React Native Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I Am currently learning react native and encountered an error "[AxiosError: Network Error]" while using "axios.get". I have tried several methods from stackoverflow and google but it didnt work.

Here Is My Code:

```
  const getData = async () => {
    await axios
      .get('https://www.reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then(({data}) => {
        setData(data.movies);
      })
      .catch(res => {
        console.warn(res);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

Comment: What if you try to use [fetch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) for this specific request to check the response or errors? Axios [will not show](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4420) some errors

Comment: I already tried fetch.It also shows "[TypeError: Network request failed]"

Comment: Next question, is it happening on the phone device on in the emulator? And probably next one - network is enabled and working? Url is reachable from browser? No VPN or Proxies or anything that can affect networking? Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163801/react-native-typeerror-network-request-failed-with-fetch), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623062/react-native-fetch-typeerror-network-request-failed), [3 github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6827)

Comment: try `.catch(res => console.warn(JSON.stringify(res))`, you'll get a better error

Comment: Url is reachable, i have checked it from thunder client, And I am using a physical device

Comment: Better Error:    {"message":"Network Error","name":"AxiosError","config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"env":{"FormData":null},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"method":"get","url":"https://www.reactnative.dev/movies.json"},"code":"ERR_NETWORK","status":null}

Comment: try opening that url in phone browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android app Network request failed for any HTTPS URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956352/react-native-android-app-network-request-failed-for-any-https-url)

Comment: also make sure you have network permissions in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem but it looks like you are mixing aysnc/await with a regular promise. Maybe try something like this:

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://www.reactnative.dev/movies.json');
    setData(data.movies);
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
  //eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);
```

Comment: It didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

use async/await or regular promise
it may not fix the issue but it's good practice

and make sure you have internet connection on emulator/device